# Set GIS region dynamically in Anylogic

Tags: gis, anylogic

I want to be able to set the coordinates of a GIS region and a GIS point dynamically (areas/points in the ocean). However, I cannot find a setX type function for the GIS regions similarly to what is available for e.g. a closed polyline.

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [API](https://anylogic.help/api/com/anylogic/engine/markup/GISRegion.html) for `GISRegion`, there is no such method. They are "static" objects.

So you need to create several of these upfront and "switch" between them using a variable `myGISRegion` of type `GISRegion`.

So create a region "Germany" and a region "France" upfront. In your agent, create a variable and change it from one region to another as needed

Comment: Thank you, Ben. Very much appreciated, as always.

Comment: Please upvote replies if they were helpful. Future users with similar problems will find these easier, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: Are you aware that if someone has a reputation under 15 they cannot upvote an answer? Check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges